# Problem with hreflang, canonical and spammy URL parameters (no return tags)

Tags: canonical-url, spam, hreflang, url-parameters

I'm facing problems of spammy parameters in Google Search Console.

I have a multilingual page (for illustration purposes, let's say that the URL is https://www.example.com/page1.html). The page is translated into multiple languages (https://fr.example.com/page1.html, https://de.example.com/page1.html, etc).

I've added the hreflang tags to each version of the page like this:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://fr.example.com/page1.html" hreflang="fr"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://de.example.com/page1.html" hreflang="de"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/page1.html" hreflang="x-default"/>
```

The problem I'm facing is that Google is crawling urls named like this:

https://fr.example.com/page1.html?some_spammy_param=more_spam

and it's complaining that the alternate pages don't link back to it (because obviously, I don't want to include auto generated spammy parameters in my hreflang parameters!).

In a single language site, this would be solved by adding a canonical tag, but Google recommends against using the canonical tag in multilingual sites.

Answer (score 1):

[Google says](https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-internationalisation#q20):

> **Q: Can I use `rel=canonical` together with `rel-alternate-hreflang`?**
>
> A: We recommend not using `rel=canonical` across different language or country versions. Using it within the same language/country version is fine and one of the recommended ways of handling canonicalization.

In other words:

> Don't mark one language as canonical as the other.   `/fr/page.html` is **NOT** the same as `/de/page.html` there should not be a canonical tag that marks one as canonical as the other.  If you mark the fr and de page as canonical, one of those two will **NOT** appear in search results, even for users that speak that language.
>
> It is fine to use a canonical tag as long as it points to the same language.  In fact, we recommend that you do so.
>
> It is completely compatible with hreflang.   Hreflang is meant to point between different languages.   rel=canonical can only point with the same language.

Each page in each language can have a canonical tag.   With both canonical and hreflang it would look like this:

- `https://fr.example.com/page1.html`:

  ```
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://fr.example.com/page1.html">
  <link rel="alternate" href="https://de.example.com/page1.html" hreflang="de"/>
  <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/page1.html" hreflang="x-default"/>
  ```
- `https://fr.example.com/page1.html?some_spammy_param=more_spam`:

  ```
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://fr.example.com/page1.html">
  <link rel="alternate" href="https://de.example.com/page1.html" hreflang="de"/>
  <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/page1.html" hreflang="x-default"/>
  ```
- `https://www.example.com/page1.html`:

  ```
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/page1.html">
  <link rel="alternate" href="https://fr.example.com/page1.html" hreflang="fr"/>
  <link rel="alternate" href="https://de.example.com/page1.html" hreflang="de"/>
  ```
- ...

Comment: Are you sure about this? Their wording is very vague....

Comment: I support many languages on coinmill.com, de.coinmill.com, es.coinmill.com, etc.   I use canonical tags and it works great.  I don't use hreflang though.

Comment: I've also added Google's actual advice to the answer and paraphrased it for clarity.